# Apenas registrar se o Checkbox estiver marcado

Tags: php

Gostaria que fosse registrado apenas se o checkbox estiver marcado, desde já agradeço

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não manifeste código com imagens. Fica difícil para ler, tem que abrir em outra aba num desktop, num portátil tem que sair da página e não permite que quem responda a pergunta use [CTRL + C], [CTRL + V].

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Termos e Condicoes">
```

PHP

```php
if(isset($_POST["checkbox"])){
   echo "Checkbox Marcado";
   ...
   // Cadastre o usuário
   ...
}else{
   echo "Checkbox Desmarcado";
   ...
   // Retorne para a página principal informando o erro
   ...
}
```

Obs: Na imagem que você postou o nome do checkbox é "chechbox", lembre de receber $_POST["chechbox"] na página php... :)